# Bayesian skepticism explained to the layperson

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I have come across several references to the fact that Bayes' Theorem has not been universally accepted historically, and that it in fact goes in and out of favor. Obviously, the pendulum has swung very much in favor of late.

For example, *Mathematics for the Million* by Lancelot Hogben characterizes the theorem as "guesswork" that has "never gained universal assent among mathematicians or scientific workers" (p. 593).

I am not extensively trained in mathematics, but I would still like to learn more about the mathematics of the controversy at a level I can easily grasp. Or is it more of a philosophical objection? Thanks for any explanations/references you can provide.

Comment: Philosophers might debate the interpretation but every rigorous and classic mathematical probability text I’ve seen gladly studies, uses, and includes Bayes’ theorem, from Kolmogorov, Feller, and many modern intro books like Freund and Soloman none of which seem (as far as I recall) to share Lancelot’s sentiment.